# Single Sign On + Microservices

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, microservices

I have a couple web apps which I will try to convert in microservices (In the future maybe I will have more). Before this, I would like to create a microservice for authentication and authorization which permits SSO.

I read a lot about [CAS](http://jasig.github.io/cas/4.1.x/index.html) but I have the feeling that seems an old solution and I don't know if it is a good idea for microservices' architecture.

On the other hand I have been researching about Oauth2, I know it is only for authorizations (but you need to be authenticated for that) so.. maybe it could be a good option. Also I have found a good guide for implement [Oauth2 SSO with Spring](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/#_sso_with_oauth2_angular_js_and_spring_security_part_v). However Oauth2 is for third-party so.. neither know if it is the best solution.

As you see, I'm a bit confused . Other terms and tecnologies are in my head like SAML, OpenId... But I don't know which choose.

Answer (score 0):

Think about [OpenID - Connect](http://openid.net/connect/). It is a SSO based on Oauth2.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ralph. I have researched about OpenID - Connect and I have found an Authentication/Authorization server called [Keycloak](http://keycloak.jboss.org/) which can be a good option... Do you know it?